# Assign multiple values within the function

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to assign multiple values within the function, say in the function:

```
fun posdiv(n,l::ls)=let val m=n in posdiv1(k,m,n,l::ls) end;
```

I want to a `let val...` like below:

```
fun posdiv(n,l::ls)=let val m=n (*and val j=greatest(l::ls) where greatest is a different function and returns a value not a list*)in posdiv1(k,m,n,l::ls) end;
```

What is the general syntax for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same syntax as assigning multiple values in other places:

```
fun posdiv (n, l::ls) =
  let
    val m = n
    val j = greatest (l::ls)
  in
      posdiv1 (k, m, n, l::ls)
  end
```